# JMeter сделать запрос к 8 api используя 1 ид

Tags: java, api, jmeter

Как настроить тест, чтобы используя один `id` получать данные с 8 мест. 
и так, чтобы в одном месте поменять этот `id` и все продолжало работать, а не в каждом тесте менять.
структура url - `server_name/recording/<id>/metadata`

Используя `HTTP Request Defaults Server name` - вписать имя сервера

В `HTTP Request Path - /recording/<id>/` (прописать путь включающий id) тест не проходит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, немного переформулируйте вопрос и грамотно изложите мысль.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете именно такой синтаксис:

```
/recording/<id>/
```

то тест не пройдет.

Если вы хотите обратиться к [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) - поменяйте путь следующим образом:

```
/recording/${id}/
```

если `id` - это [JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/), значение можно прочитать с помощью функции [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

```
/recording/${__P(id)}/
```